# select pages for pdf print

Tags: pdf, evince

I am printing the current page of a pdf file in evince. But I found that in evince, there are two different page numbers showing the current page. If I choose the one shown in an input box, that will print out the wrong page, but if I choose the one shown inside the parenthesis after the input box, that will be the correct one. I was wondering

1. what is the difference between the
   two numbers shown for the current
   page?
2. why selecting pages for printing
   works that way?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tim,

Evince displays the page numbers in parenthesis based on the logical/actual sequence of pages; that is, the real page numbers if you used only 1 - n (instead of i, ii, iii, 1).

The numbers in the input box are the numbers (or "name") given to the page. For example i, ii, and so on.

This is an issue with any type of document/reader that uses mixed or after actual first page numbering.

Comment: Thanks! Is the number in the input box the result of so-called "pagination"?

Comment: Yes. The pagination is what is shown in the input box. Download Jono Bacon's [The art of community](http://www.artofcommunityonline.org/downloads/jonobacon-theartofcommunity-1ed.pdf) for a good example of this in action.